# Powershell and ssh when running rabbit

Tags: powershell, ssh, rabbitmq

I have ssh on to a ubuntu box  and run the following:

```
rabbitmq-server –detached
```

Which I believe should give me the command prompt back and run rabbit in the background, howerver it justs hangs:

[image]

Is this a powershell issue?

Comment: I dont think this is related to the tag PowerShell as it is a Windows technology

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is a component of Microsoft Windows, it has a command-line shell and a scripting environment. So I don't think you question is relative to PowerShell.